# Track Favorite questions

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

In some questions I see the Star clicked and the numbers.

How to know who have Hit favorite (starred) your questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been discussed over on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824).  In summary:

- You can't directly see who favorited a particular question.
- You could roll up a query on [Stack Exchange Data](http://data.stackexchange.com/) if you want, but keep in mind that the data there lags real-time.
- You can see a user's favorites; this is public to all.